# click event delay and pre loader animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to combine two techniques in page transition. first, when user click a link , the click event should be delayed about 200ms and displaying css animation (ex: fading), after that the new page will  be loaded normally. Then, for visitors with slow internet connection, they will be presented with pre-loader right after the first animation. The problem is, it seems both techniques doesn't fit each others. Any advice guys?

PS: Actually I inspired by these guys website : http://rsq.com/

here's my code:

```
$body = $("body");
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () {
        $body.addClass("loading"); //for slow connection, visitors with faster connection may not notice this...
    },
    ajaxStop: function () {
        $body.removeClass("loading");
    }
});
$('a').on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') != '#') {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#wrapper').addClass('fade_animation'); //animation right before new page request
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = href
        }, 200);                
        return false;
        $.post($(this).attr('href'));
    }    
});
```

Comment: Anything after the return false; will not be invoked

Comment: Yes, you're right. but the return false is required for the fading animation to work properly, but it kills the ajax post (which is required by pre-loader animation. this is really confusing. i've tried put the ajax post inside the setTimeout, but no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

I think this is enough:

Instead of:

```
    return false;
    $.post($(this).attr('href'));
```

do this

```
    $.post($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
```

So the `$.post` gets executed.

Comment: it seems the preloader appears with fading animation simultaneously to me. Anyway, thanks for the clue :)

Comment: Could you increase your timeout to 3000 (with the change I suggested above) and confirm me if you see it simoultaneous?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution , but don't know if it's a good way, but it works.

```
$('a').on("click", function(){

        if($(this).attr('href') != '#')
        {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#wrapper, footer').addClass('fading animation');
            setTimeout(function() {
                // window.location = href
                $.post(window.location = href) // this line works :)
            }, 200);
        return false;
            // $.post($(this).attr('href'));    
        }

    });
```